# Template Does not found error on one view but other works fine.both are same settings same file

Tags: python, django

i am doing a employee employer site 
authentication part.in mysite i am getting template not found error on one while other is working fine/what might be the issue? my codes are below

settings.py

```
from os.path import join
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

```
views.py
<pre><code>
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def employer_signup(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
  form = EmployerSignupForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
   content = form.save(commit=False)
   content.is_employer = True
   content.save()
 else:
       content = EmployerSignupForm()
       print content.errors

 return render_to_response( "employer_signup.html", {'form':content},  context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def employee_signup(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
  form = EmployeeSignupForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
   content = form.save(commit=False)
   content.is_employee = True
   content.save()
 else:
       content = EmployeeSignupForm()
       print content.errors

 return render_to_response( "employee_signup.html", {'form':content},  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
</code></pre>
```

this is my traceback.how to debug this?

```
tracebck
/home/niyas/django/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/niyas/django/mysite/jobsite/views.py in employee_signup
 return render_to_response( "employee_signup.html", {'form':content},  context_instance=RequestContext(request)) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/niyas/django/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py in render_to_response
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/niyas/django/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in render_to_string
        t = get_template(template_name, dirs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/niyas/django/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name, dirs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/niyas/django/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Try debug from traceback.

Comment: traceback its just showing up as 500 instead 200

Comment: I am talking about the django traceback on the django error page. Your DEBUG is set to True right , in settings.py ?

Comment: Post the complete traceback then only we can help you.

Comment: posted guys please check

Answer (score 0):

Probably a typo in the name of the file. Also check the case of the letters in the filename.

Comment: have you checked the case of the filename?

Answer (score 0):

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
}, ]
```

Try this in settings.py

Comment: Which folder are you placing templates?

Comment: inside my project folder

Comment: For this particular code snippet. Templates folder would be at the root folder.

Comment: cant understand can u make it bit clear?
my project folder = mysite
app folder = jobsite1 and the virtualenv folder = django